# Is there an security risk with using wp_signon function?

Tags: wp-signup

**Question 1:**
I'm new to wp and trying to write a plugin for custom register and login.
There is a function called [wp_signon()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) which can help to login the user, but can i just use get variables from user and call the function Or i should first filter them?

Answer (score 0):

You should first filter to check for valid user credentials

[wp_authenticate_username_password](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate_username_password)